# Get first value above current (stored procedure)

Tags: sql-server, sorting, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Currently I'm working on a stored procedure to update the sort order of a table. The idea is to make sure that the correct rows are swapped.

INPUT: ToMoveID INT, Up BIT (1 up, 0 down)

SERVER: MSSQL 2012

example to use:

```
ID  SortOrder   UseForSwap
1   1           Yes
2   NULL        No
3   2           Yes
4   NULL        No
5   3           Yes
```

The idea is to put the row with ID 5 higher, the ID of 3 is **unkown** at this point. How Can i get the ID of the row with te **first** **sortorder** higher as the current?

Sample values: TomoveID = 5, Up = 1

After sorting the result shoud be:

```
ID  SortOrder   UseForSwap
1   1           Yes
2   NULL        No
3   3           Yes
4   NULL        No
5   2           Yes
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add version of sql server and sample input and output data

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Edited the question, there is no output. It only needs to swap the sortorder values

Comment: It is still unclear. I mean show us some set of rows and what result do you expect after applying sorting table to those rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a row with the biggest SortOrder that is less than SortOrder of ID 5 row in this way:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    tbl.ID
FROM YourTable tbl
WHERE tbl.SortOrder < (SELECT SortOrder FROM YourTable tbl2 WHERE tbl2.ID = 5)
ORDER BY
    tbl.SortOrder DESC
```

Comment: Wow forgetting DESC was my problem, thanks. Feel stupid now :)